# softwareupdate grep Script Help

Tags: terminal, bash

Using High Sierra I have this set as a cronjob to run once a day.

I've been struggling to work out how to get grep to find the string in the output. Am fairly new to bash scripting.

Any advice on where I went wrong, and examples are appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash

printf '\e[2t'

check=$(softwareupdate -l)

sleep 5

echo $check


if [ fgrep "No new software" <<< $check ]
then
say "Peter, You are up to date"
else
say "Peter, you have updates"
fi
```

Comment: Do you need the content of `$check` later on in the script?

Comment: All I want is that if there are any updates at all - it does a say to tell me, and if the software update -l comes back as empty it tells me theres nothing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`softwareupdate` prints `No new software available.` on `stderr`, not on `stdout`, so it will never get assigned to `check`. The quick fix is to run

```
check=$(softwareupdate -l 2>&1)
```

This will redirect stderr (file descriptor 2) to stdout (file descriptor 1).

Also your `if` statement is wrong, the `[` is a command, not just syntax. So you can simply run

```
if fgrep "No new software" <<< $check; then
```

for this.

But if you don't need the value of `$check` later on you can put all this in one line and just run

```
if softwareupdate -l 2>&1 | fgrep -q "No new software"; then
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you confirm what 2>&1 is doing? Does it just mean if it is > 1 character?

Comment: @Pete see edited answer